# LibCURL when used on Mac with C

Tags: c, libcurl

Basically, I'm trying to simply use libCURL to download a web site and I've been using this code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <curl/curl.h>

int main(void)
{
  CURL *curl;
  CURLcode res;

  curl = curl_easy_init();
  if(curl) {
    curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_URL, "http://google.com");
    res = curl_easy_perform(curl);

    /* always cleanup */ 
    curl_easy_cleanup(curl);
  }
  return 0;
}
```

And getting this error:

```
Undefined symbols:
   "_curl_easy_perform", referenced from:
      _main in ccGyMZQR.o
  "_curl_easy_init", referenced from:
      _main in ccGyMZQR.o
  "_curl_easy_setopt", referenced from:
      _main in ccGyMZQR.o
  "_curl_easy_cleanup", referenced from:
      _main in ccGyMZQR.o
    ld: symbol(s) not found
    collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You need to link to the cURL library.

If you're using gcc, try compiling using

> gcc -lcurl file.c

That specifies that you need to link against libcURL.