# libcurl wont work xcode

Tags: c++, xcode, libcurl

I'm having the exact same issue this individual is having:

[LibCURL when used on Mac with C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4719071/libcurl-when-used-on-mac-with-c)

However I'm not sure how to apply the fix. To run my code, I hit "build and Run" in xcode, I'm not sure how to resolve the issue because of this.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Add `-lcurl` to the Other Linker Flags (OTHER_LDFLAGS) build setting for the target.